# SQL UPDATE statement to update a column based on another existing row

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a table that has similar format to the below table.

What I want to do is update Col4 based on this logic

- if Col2 is null then update Col4 with Col3
- if Col2 is not null then  find the the value in Col1 which matches the value in Col2.  update col4 with with the corresponding value in col3

For example given this table:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
-----------------------------
|  1   |   2  |  A1  |  2   |
-----------------------------
|  2   |   3  |  A2  |  3   |
-----------------------------
|  3   |{null}|  A3  |{null}|
```

Update it to be this table

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
-----------------------------
|  1   |   2  |  A1  |  A2  |
-----------------------------
|  2   |   3  |  A2  |  A3  |
-----------------------------
|  3   |{null}|  A3  |  A3  |
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which DB? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the CASE statement?

Comment: I`m using MySQL 5.1.  I`ve already tried similar logic to the update set from in SQL Server but to no avail.  I will be eventually implementing a Case statement but the problem I`m having is performing the logic when it is not null

Comment: Could you post the code that you already tried, and the error it gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
UPDATE  table
SET     col4 = CASE WHEN table.col2 IS NULL THEN table.col3 ELSE col2Matches.col3 END
FROM    table
        INNER JOIN table AS col2Matches
            ON  table.col2 = col2Matches.col1
```

this should let you test it:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN table.col2 IS NULL THEN table.col3 ELSE col2Matches.col3 END
FROM    table
        INNER JOIN table AS col2Matches
            ON  table.col2 = col2Matches.col1
```

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: Make it a left outer join for when Col2 is null.

Comment: The first portion of the CASE WHEN takes care of Col2 being NULL. I made it an INNER as the OP is only concerned about when it is NOT null.

Comment: Philip is right.  I lose the third row if I make it an inner join.

Comment: My point was that, while a left join will certainly get the job done, you are selecting more rows than you need to do so and this makes the query less efficient. You do indeed lose Row 3 from `col2Matches` but you don't need it as you are getting that value from `table` instead (where Row 3 most certainly exists). Either way, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would probably work in Oracle.

```
update myTable
set col4 = case when col2 is null then col3
                else (select col3 from myTable where col1 = col2)
           end;
```

Of course, if `select col3 from myTable where col1 = col2` returns multiple rows then this query will not work. But I imagine you know already know if your data is clean enough for this to work.