# SQL: How to update Column A with "100" where Column B is not null

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column named "CodeField' that has null and not null cells, when that column is not null I want another column named "PercentField" to be updated with the following text "100".

How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Despite the simplicity of the problem being asked, I'm going to have to -1 this because it has been asked many times before (quick examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065509/sql-update-statement-to-update-a-column-based-on-another-existing-row) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860465/sql-query-to-update-one-column-based-on-data-from-another), and probably many other questions too), and it shows no research effort or first attempt.

Answer (score 4):

```
update your_table
set PercentField = '100'
where CodeField is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET PercentField = '100' 
WHERE CodeField IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME set PercentField = '100' where CodeField is not null
```

If you want to learn SQL, Refer this Link, it will help you to improve a lot

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp